# Auto Format and Diff XML

Tags: xml, diff

I have two xml files and I want to diff them.

The problem is the xml files are not formatted and are all in one line. Regular diff tools I found cannot auto format them.

I wonder if any tool out there can do this (need to be able to be called in a command prompt).
OR
is there a auto formater that I can call in command prompt so that I will call the diff tool afterwards.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ is a fine tool which indents your XML, so it's easier to diff. There's a port of the GNU diff tool with MinGW MSYS (or Cygwin). WinMerge is a fine graphical diff tool that I personally prefer.

Comment: You can call WinMerge from the command prompt yes, but it will open a graphical Window. If you need it to be command-line only, you can use the tidy tool, and pipe that to the GNU diff tool that comes with MinGW (or actually, http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ is even simpler than MinGW if you like).

Comment: no, forget what I said about piping :-) that's probably not practical for diffing. But you can use the tidy tool to save to for example tmp1.xml and tmp2.xml, and then diff tmp1.xml tmp2.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line program [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) will can format and canonicalize your xml in different ways:

```
xmllint --format file.xml > formatted_file.xml

xmllint --c14n file.xml > canonicalized_file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tidy and diff on the command-line like this:

```
diff <(tidy -q -xml file1.xml) <(tidy -q -xml file2.xml)
```

You might want to add -indent to the tidy-commands.